# How to run multiple odoo services of diiferent version E.g odoo-10 and odoo-11 together in windows8

Tags: windows, postgresql, odoo-10, odoo-11

I have installed an independent postgresSql version 9.1 (x86). Then i simply had installed odoo-11 service without the postgresql because i already have it. After that I had to download the odeo11 source code and configure it in pycharm here is the screen shot of my odoo configuration.I had used different postgresql user for each odoo version.

[image]

here is my odoo.conf

```
[options] 
; This is the password That Allows database operations: 
; admin_passwd = admin 
db_host = localhost 
db_port = 5432 
db_user = openpg 
dbfilter =odoo11
db_password = openpgpwd 
addons_path = d: \ odoo \ addons 
xmlrpc_port = 8088
```

Futher i had debugged with pycharm and i was successfull in installing odoo-11

But i had installed odoo10 using same method then my odoo11 install got conflicted with odoo11 and console shows me error

> Skipping database pos10 as its base version is not 11.0.1.3

But my odoo10 is working fine now.
here is my odoo.conf of odoo10

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = openpg1
dbfilter=odoo10
db_password = 123
addons_path = D:\odoo-10.0\odoo-10.0\addons
xmlrpc_port = 8080
```

here is the configuration of odoo10 instance

[image]

Comment: Did you solve yout problem??? I want to do that in linux, PS: odoo .v11 use Python > 3.5.x and odoo .v10 2.7.x > Python > 3.x.

Comment: yes  i had solved simply use pycharm then easily you can use both version on same machine ether on linux or windows .

Comment: But you have to run one at a time . Other wise database  as its base version is not error will occur for you.

Comment: Are you using environment variables for each version? or Docker? How do you handle conflicts of different dependencies in each version? or you don't have any? can you give me some tips, my email: salcedo.salazar at g.m.a.i.l. Tnks

Comment: yes i am using pycharm , i have same posgresql server for both instance. I run odoo 11 using python 3.5 and odoo 10 using python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run multiple odoo server at the same time like I am running odoo10, odoo11, odoo12 and as well odoo13 at the same time.

**1**- First their ports should be different.

**2**- And run it by using terminal or cmd or pycharm.

*Note: Different versions never run on same browser window you have to open other window in private mode.*

Comment: And they should have different store directory too because Odoo saves the session files there and this why you cannot open two session even in two ports in the same browser

Comment: The key that solved my problem when running multiple Odoo in the same machine are:
`Different versions never run on same browser window you have to open other window in private mode.`
Thanks Man.